# Spring Environment - multiple?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-environment

I am confused about how Spring Environment works.  I thought it is basically a singleton bean in the `ApplicationContext` and anytime I load `PropertySources` into my AppCtx, they combine into this *single* `Environment` automatically.  However, I am seeing this logged many times in my app, which means the constructor of `AbstractEnvironment` is getting called many times:

```
2015-01-06 12:16:26,858 DEBUG (main) [org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment] Adding [systemProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2015-01-06 12:16:26,858 DEBUG (main) [org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment] Adding [systemEnvironment] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2015-01-06 12:16:26,858 DEBUG (main) [org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment] Initialized StandardEnvironment with PropertySources [systemProperties,systemEnvironment]
```

The results are that I do things like:

```
@Autowire
Environment environment;

String propertyIExpect = environment.getProperty("myprop");
```

And I get an instance of the `Environment`, but no properties I expected to be present are in it.

I expected them to have been added to this auto-wired `Environment` when I added this XML to my Spring Boot application context:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:/spring/environment/${ctms.env}/application.properties" order="1"/>
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:build.info" order="2"/>
```

Then again, sometimes the `Environment` properties are there as shown in this logging:

```
2015-01-06 12:16:37,433 TRACE (main) [org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver] getProperty("ctms.env", String)
2015-01-06 12:16:37,433 DEBUG (main) [org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver] Searching for key 'ctms.env' in [servletConfigInitParams]
2015-01-06 12:16:37,433 DEBUG (main) [org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver] Searching for key 'ctms.env' in [servletContextInitParams]
2015-01-06 12:16:37,433 DEBUG (main) [org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver] Searching for key 'ctms.env' in [systemProperties]
2015-01-06 12:16:37,433 DEBUG (main) [org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver] Found key 'ctms.env' in [systemProperties] with type [String] and value 'dev'
2015-01-06 12:16:37,438 DEBUG (main) [org.springframework.core.env.MutablePropertySources] Adding [environmentProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2015-01-06 12:16:37,438 INFO  (main) [org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer] Loading properties file from class path resource [spring/environment/dev/application.properties]
2015-01-06 12:16:37,438 DEBUG (main) [org.springframework.core.env.MutablePropertySources] Adding [localProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2015-01-06 12:16:37,443 TRACE (main) [org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver] getProperty("database.connection.url", String)
2015-01-06 12:16:37,443 DEBUG (main) [org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver] Searching for key 'database.connection.url' in [environmentProperties]
2015-01-06 12:16:37,443 TRACE (main) [org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver] getProperty("database.connection.url", String)
2015-01-06 12:16:37,443 DEBUG (main) [org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver] Searching for key 'database.connection.url' in [servletConfigInitParams]
2015-01-06 12:16:37,443 DEBUG (main) [org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver] Searching for key 'database.connection.url' in [servletContextInitParams]
2015-01-06 12:16:37,443 DEBUG (main) [org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver] Searching for key 'database.connection.url' in [systemProperties]
2015-01-06 12:16:37,443 DEBUG (main) [org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver] Searching for key 'database.connection.url' in [systemEnvironment]
2015-01-06 12:16:37,443 DEBUG (main) [org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver] Searching for key 'database.connection.url' in [random]
2015-01-06 12:16:37,443 DEBUG (main) [org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver] Searching for key 'database.connection.url' in [applicationConfig: [classpath:/application.properties]]
2015-01-06 12:16:37,443 DEBUG (main) [org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver] Could not find key 'database.connection.url' in any property source. Returning [null]
2015-01-06 12:16:37,443 DEBUG (main) [org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver] Searching for key 'database.connection.url' in [localProperties]
2015-01-06 12:16:37,443 DEBUG (main) [org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver] Found key 'database.connection.url' in [localProperties] with type [String] and value 'jdbc:oracle:thin:@somehost:someport/foo'
```

NOTE: I am also seeing this in the Spring Boot logs 2 times:

```
12:19:03,387 INFO  [TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer] Tomcat started on port(s): 8080/http
```

I would've expected this one time at the end.  Perhaps this is related?  Am I somehow creating multiple `ApplicationContext`s in my Spring Boot app?

Comment: You will usually see 2 contexts: servlet & root. However, I would be suspicious of what else might be in that "Spring Boot" XML configuration file and how it's being loaded. The existence of such a file could indicate that it's not a Spring Boot application. If it is a Spring Boot app and that is a Spring XML configuration file, then you're likely to be loading two contexts (servlet & root) based on that file and Spring Boot will also be loading a servlet and root context.

Comment: Generally your xml is ignored when using Spring Boot and you should just use `@PropertySource` to load additional property files. However the easiest solution is to simply add your properties to the default loaded `application.properties` file.

Comment: @Steve - Oh it's definitely a Spring Boot app. In fact, you might say its a case study in how to move a legacy app from JBoss EAP & Spring to Spring Boot alone (w/ embedded JMS, JNDI, JTA, and JCA).  My app is 10 years old, ~500K lines, and over 250 Spring beans in XML with no time to re-factor them all to Java. No Web or Dispatcher XMLs.  But, the old XML-based beans loading into Spring Boot with ImportResource on a Configuration annotated class.  They load just fine!  It is this one Environment detail that has confused me.  That is the only thing that is not loading fine.

Answer (score 1):

An XML `<context:property-placeholder/>` is not added to the `Environment`. The DEBUG logs are just noise, so probably ignorable. If you need it in the `Environment` then use the Spring Boot APIs to set the property locations (or possibly us `@PropertySource`).

Answer (score 0):

From the advice posted here, I no longer load the properties file: **classpath:/spring/${ctms.env}/application.properties** from a `<context:property-placeholder>` XML.

**This is how I resolved my Environment properties issue:**

Since ${ctms.env} is essentially the environment we are running in and also reflected in a Spring active profile (e.g., dev, test, stage, prod), I ended up using Spring Boot's feature to auto-load active profile properties files "by convention" for me.

To clarify, this Spring Boot feature will look for .properties files in specific locations based on the active profiles.  Like this:

For a Spring Active Profile = "foo", it would auto-load this file, if it exists:

`WEB-INF/classes/config/application-foo.properties`

For my solution, I re-locate and re-name the properties file in my Spring Boot WAR to like this:

`/WEB-INF/classes/config/application-${ctms-env}.properties`

It basically ends up being something like:
For "dev" Spring Active Profile:

`/WEB-INF/classes/config/application-dev.properties`

For "test" Spring Active Profile:

`/WEB-INF/classes/config/application-test.properties`

For "stage" Spring Active Profile:

`/WEB-INF/classes/config/application-stage.properties`

etc.

I didn't have to re-write any properties files.  I just had to re-package them the way Spring Boot "conventions" want to find/load them.  And, then of course, stop loading via the XML way.  And it works great.